# Redirect URL without showing new URL?

Tags: url, redirect, mod-proxy

Is it possible to redirect URL in to another URL without showing the new URL?

eg:

When users go to www.sample1.com/page1.html , it should show www.sample2.com/page2.html . But URL needs to be showing like it belongs to www.sample1.com , or something like this www.subdomain.sample1.com/blah.html.

I need to host some pages for another domain , but those pages should look like they belong to that domain or to a subdomain of that domain.

Using an iframe is not an option in my circumstances,any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to use `mod_proxy` to display all the sample2.com pages in a sub-context:

```
ProxyPass   /sample2   http://www.sample2.com
```

Thus, `sample2.com/page2.html` would display as `sample1.com/sample2/page2.html`.

Otherwise [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) may be of use as well, specifically the [`proxy|P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Hope that helps.